# Making Leaflet Map fullscreen in RShiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, leaflet

I'm having trouble making my leaflet map in Shiny go fullscreen. While I can obviously just manually set the width and height of the map to my screen-size, I'd like to the map to adapt to whatever screen-size it is shown on.

How do I go about automating the size of the map?

Here's the code I've been trying so far. Unfortunately, however, this doesn't adjust the height properly.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

location=c(46.52433,10.12633)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#map {height:100%, width:100%;}"))),

  leafletOutput("map")


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles()  %>% setView(lat = location[1],lng = location[2],zoom = 10) %>% 
      addMarkers(lat = location[1],lng = location[2],popup = "Test") })


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `width = "100%", height = "100%"` to `leafletOutput` and using `fillPage()` like below:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

location=c(46.52433,10.12633)

ui <- fillPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%; height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")

  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles()  %>% setView(lat = location[1],lng = 
location[2],zoom = 10) %>% 
      addMarkers(lat = location[1], lng = location[2],popup = "Test") })


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This doesn't work -- that just makes a blank page appear. I don't think actually setting the height in the leafletOutput() statement to anything other than a pixel-specific height works, thats why I think a CSS workaround might be required.

Comment: Try it with `type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%; height:100%}"` inside `tags$style()`

Comment: Thanks for being so responsive @monarque13. Unfortunatley, that didn't work either. Just so that we're on the same page, this is what I have as my tags() statement:
```  tags$head(tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%; height:100%}")),
```
There is no reference to the map element (though I've tried that using #map after body, and it doesn't  either). Any other ideas?

Comment: Glad to hear. Please consider upvoting/accepting my answer if you like.

Comment: Had just been waiting to see if there was any difference between the two answers, but I've marked yours as the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript:

```
js <- '
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(){
  $("#map").css({
    width: window.innerWidth, 
    height: window.innerHeight
  });
  $(window).on("resize", function(e){
    if(e.target instanceof Window){
      $("#map").css({width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight});
    }
  });
})
'
location=c(46.52433,10.12633)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("html,body {margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}")),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  ......
```

Comment: Thanks, Stephane! So both this and the edited approach from monarque13 work. Are there any differences or pros/cons to either solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple and uncomplicated solution then try view height and it shall do the thing

```
if(interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(leaflet)
  
  location = c(46.52433, 10.12633)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(leafletOutput("map", height = "100vh"))
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$map = renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
        setView(lat = location[1],
                lng = location[2],
                zoom = 10) %>%
        addMarkers(lat = location[1],
                   lng = location[2],
                   popup = "Test")
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

This solution will work fine if you want to put it within an element also.

Keep Coding!