# Making a leaflet map fullscreen in an RShiny dashboard

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, leaflet

I'm working on creating an RShiny dashboard with a leaflet map; I want my map to be fullscreen, but I can't quite seem to get the borders/margins to go away. I have tried the solutions offered in a previous post [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61341817/making-leaflet-map-fullscreen-in-rshiny)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61341817/making-leaflet-map-fullscreen-in-rshiny), but with those solutions I just get a completely blank screen--the map does not seem to render at all. Here is my code:

```r
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# UI
ui <- navbarPage("Dashboard",
                 tabPanel("Fullscreen Map",
                          fillPage(
                                 leafletOutput("map", width = "98vw", height = "90vh"))
                          )
)

# FUNCTION
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
                            leaflet() %>% 
                            addTiles() %>% 
                            setView(lat = 0, lng = 0, zoom = 5)
    })
}

# RUN APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see, my current workaround is to set the map size based on view height/view width (`width = "98vw", height = "90vh"`). If I set either of those to 100, the right and bottom edges of the map go off the screen. Again, I have tried both solutions offered in the post I have linked above and both do not work. Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with HTML, CSS, or JavaScript to really adjust the code in the answers for my situation.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or solutions!

EDIT: Below is a screenshot to help @L D

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the point is to maximize the map over the page up to the navbar and to the left and right and down to the bottom, try the following, it may be too quick and dirty for you though.

It disables the padding/margin of the Shiny components throught CSS:

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- navbarPage("Dashboard",
                 tabPanel("Fullscreen Map",
                          fillPage(
                            leafletOutput("map", width = "100vw", height = "100vh"))
                 ),
                 header=tags$style(HTML("
                                        .container-fluid{
                                          padding: 0px !important;
                                        }
                                        .navbar{
                                          margin-bottom: 0px !important;
                                        }"))
)

# FUNCTION
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lat = 0, lng = 0, zoom = 5)
  })
}

# RUN APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit: The JavaScript version**

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)


# UI
resizeJS <- "
  function resizeMap(e){
        $('#map').css({top: $('.navbar').height() });
  }

  $(window).on('resize', resizeMap);
  $(window).ready(resizeMap);
"

ui <- navbarPage("Dashboard",
                 tabPanel("Fullscreen Map",
                          fillPage(
                            leafletOutput("map", width = "auto", height = "auto"))
                 ),
                 header=tags$head( tags$style(HTML("
                                        #map{
                                          border: 3px solid red; /* display border around the map */
                                          position: fixed;
                                          left: 0px;
                                          right: 0px;
                                          bottom: 0px;
                                          top: 0px;
                                        }
                                        .navbar{
                                          margin-bottom: 0px !important;
                                        }")),
                                   tags$script(resizeJS))
)

# FUNCTION
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lat = 0, lng = 0, zoom = 5)
  })
}

# RUN APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This should keep the map aligned perfectly into the window.

Comment: This solution mostly works—thank you so much for your help! One issue I have is that it removes the margin from the navbar, making the “Fullscreen Map” justified slightly to the left. Is there any way to fix this easily? Either way, I very much appreciate your solution!

Comment: @metamorporpoise could you make a screenshot and color out what do you mean?

Comment: @L D I uploaded an image to help demonstrate. The orange shaded part is what is lost!

Comment: @L D I am sort of able to fix the issue by attaching three invisible unicode characters before "Dashboard," which adds a margin to the next in the nabber, but this is also a little quick and dirty, so if there are any immediate solutions that are a little more dynamic that would be great. If not, thank you for your help!

Comment: @metamorporpoise i see, it is caused by the .container-fluid selector turning off the padding, it is also contained in the navbar. so we can modify the map itself to align to the left, i'll edit the answer

Comment: @L D this fix works too!! Thanks so much